# How can I disable only the left speaker on a Macbook Air?

Tags: macbook, speakers

My left speaker is busted and distorts like crazy. I have gone into **System Preferences -> Sound** and balanced the sound to the far right. That works, but then when I plug in a USB audio interface or some headphones the setting resets, and I have to go back into **System Preferences -> Sound** and pan back to center. Is there a way to tell my Mac not to use the left speaker?

Note: I'm quite comfortable using the Terminal.

Comment: In other words: I want to disable the speaker rather than routing the signal to the right.

Comment: Is opening the Mac out of the question too then?

Comment: Hmmm.. Might be  worth answering with that nonetheless if you have the know-how. May helps someone else, seems like no too many answers so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the instructions will vary depending on which Mac model you are using, another option is to open up the notebook, and either disconnect or plug the speaker. There are sites available (such as [iFixIt](http://www.ifixit.com)) that have step-by-step instructions on how to open them up.

Again, if you can just disconnect the speaker, it will solve the problem, but depending on the notebook, it may be a simply plug or you may need to unsolder a connection. As with anything inside of a system, be careful, and ask for help if needed

Answer (score 8):

Go to Settings

> System Prefs -> Sound -> Balance.

Change this to full left or full right depending on which one is the working speaker.

Comment: The OP knows how to do this,  and the question explains why it’s not an adequate solution.

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for that! The OP knows how to do it, but it was perfect for my problem.